# Adjust the text to fit the background image to print it A4

Tags: html, css

I need to insert text to fit in the background image, but when I set the positions of the letters one by one, and then print preview, the position of the letters is different. How do I solve this?

```css
body {
  page-break-inside: auto;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

{
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto
}

div2 {
  font-size: 12px
}

.one {
  background-image: url("image2001.png");
  background-size: 21cm 29.7cm;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head></head>

<body class="one">
  <div2>2020.10.08</div2>
  <div2 style="position:absolute; left:160px; top: 80px;">Tel: 053-593-8292</div2>
  <div2 style="position:absolute; left:270px; top: 80px;">Fax: 053-593-8291</div2>
  <div2 style="position:absolute; left:380px; top: 80px;">1-1/1</div2>
  ' ' '

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: My advice, lay out the grid in css exactly like your paper, cover the grid div with your image as background and position it in the center on both x and y axes. Fill in the grid elements. This way your print will work on any size paper when you print.

Comment: Thank you We have succeeded in implementation based on this!